# How to increase the Zoom Level of Google Maps in wordpress

Tags: google-maps, latitude-longitude

Here is the code I have written to add a marker to the google map by providing latitude and longitude. The problem is that I am not getting a zoomed google map. I have tried setting the zoom level to 12 but this has no effect to the closed map.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var lat = 49.892231;
var lng = -97.132530;    
var zoomLevel = 12;
var allMarkers = [];
var curMarkerInder = 0;
var site_url = "<?php echo bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') ?>";
var map_left = 270;
var map_top = 234;
var bounds ;

function open_window(markerId){

    GEvent.trigger(allMarkers[markerId-1],"click");
}


if (latLangs.length > 0){
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
        zoom: zoomLevel,
        scrollwheel: false,
        draggable: false,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
    mapOptions);
    bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
}else{
    $("#map").remove();
}

function markeradd(lat,lng,content){
    var image = site_url + "/images/red.png"

    var markerOptions = {
        map: map,
        icon: image,       
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng)
    };
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);
    var content = content;
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(e) {
        var infobox = new SmartInfoWindow({
            position: marker.getPosition(),
            map: map,
            content: content
        });
    });
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
    bounds.extend(myLatLng);    
    //map.setCenter(myLatLng);
    //map.setZoom(zoomLevel);
}
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    function createMarker(point,html,i) {

        var image = site_url + "/images/red.png"
        var Icon = new GIcon();

        Icon.image = image;
        Icon.iconSize = new GSize(30, 52);
        Icon.shadowSize = new GSize(36, 34);
        Icon.iconAnchor = new GPoint(5, 34);
        Icon.infoWindowAnchor = new GPoint(5, 2);
        Icon.infoShadowAnchor = new GPoint(14, 25);

        opts = { 
            "icon": Icon,
            "labelText": "A",
            "labelOffset": new GSize(-6, -10),
            "clickable": true
        };

        var marker = new GMarker(point,opts);

        allMarkers[i] = marker;

        marker.hide();

        GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
            marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html);
            last_marker = marker;
        });
        return marker;
    }

    for(var i=0; i < latLangs.length; i++) {
        markeradd(latLangs[i]['lat'],latLangs[i]['lng'],latLangs[i]['address']);
    }
    map.fitBounds(bounds);

    $("#menu-item-3122").addClass('current_page_item');
    $("#menu-item-3123").addClass('current_page_item');
});
</script>
```

How can i increase the level of zoom for this case?
Please give me any Suggestions...

Comment: Is the map not zooming to fit the markers as you coded it to do (`map.fitBounds(bounds);`)?  If that is the case, you can prevent it from changing the zoom level by removing that line.

Answer (score 2):

The map is zooming to fit the markers, as coded it here: `map.fitBounds(bounds);`.

To stop that from happening, remove that line.